webpack devServer: how to open browser using local IP address instead of localhost
I am developing for mobile React apps, and use a QR code on the page to set my mobile browser to the address of my test page on my desktop.
Currently the devServer always opens to localhost, and I need to manually change the IP in the browser because a QR pointing to localhost won't go anywhere when reading a QR on a mobile.
My question is: in webpack.config.js, in the devServer section is there a way to open the browser using local IP address instead of localhost?
I tried various configurations but the browser always started at localhost

I did see the post and it is indeed similar. I added my solution there. It uses a webpack plugin.
